# Strange behavior of re.match function in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In the following code, I expect the program to print "Match", because `"\D+\d"` matches the `"x4"` part of the string. But it does not print anything. What is the problem?

```
import re
pattern = r"\D+\d"
if re.match(pattern, "1x4"):
    print("Match");
```

Thanks

Comment: You want `re.search`, not `re.match`. (There are many duplicate questions out there)

Comment: `re.match()` matches the beginning of the string.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, It was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that `re.match` can match anywhere inside a string is wrong.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match

> If zero or more characters *at the beginning of string* match this regular expression, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance. Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Use `re.search()` instead.

Comment: for what it's worth, I think the API is wrong. It's too late to change it anyway.